# Mailman Sender Filter RegEx not working

Tags: filtering, mailing-list

Does anyone have experience with sender filters using regular expressions with Mailman?

I use this regex to automatically accept all emails in the form "john.doe@sales.my-domain.de" or "name.name@anything.my-domain.de":

^(.*@.*my-domain.de).*$

On the other hand emails whose sender do not match this pattern should be automatically discarded with ^(?!.*@.*uni-augsburg.de).*$

The settings are the following:
[image]
[image]

Still Emails from e.g. john.doe@sales.my-domain.de are being hold and waiting for moderation. Why is that? Does anyone know?

I'm using Mailman 2.1.13

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems with your regex.  First, the dot in my-domain.de needs to be escaped.  I also don't see the need for the parenthesis.  This should work:

```
^.*@.*example\.edu$
```

That should solve the first problem of posts from your domain being held for moderation.  Keep in mind addresses can be easily spoofed and trick Mailman into allowing the message.

Comment: thank you for your answer! unfortunately, this did not work. Using your regex for auto-accepting senders, an email from name.name@sub.example.edu was again being hold for moderation... any ideas?

Comment: strangely when I send an email myself (my.name@student.example.edu) it is automatically being accepted! But my email address does only differ to the other sender's address in the part left of the @ and the subdomain. I have no explanation.